# Given a divergent series, find a smaller divergent one.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $u_n$ be a positive sequence such that $\sum u_n$ diverges.
>
> Find $(v_n)$ such that $v_n=o(u_n)$ and $\sum v_n$ diverges.

This is a difficult problem I'm stuck with.

Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, $\lim f(n)/f(n)=1$, so $f\neq o(f)$, by the [usual meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Comment: Apparently, I was making a mistake here.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the sequence

> $$v_n=\frac{u_n}{U_n}\qquad\text{with}\qquad U_n=\sum\limits_{k\leqslant n}u_k.$$

Then, for every $n$, $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^Nv_k\geqslant\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^N\frac{u_k}{U_N}=1-\frac{U_n}{U_N}\to1$ when $N\to\infty$ hence the rests $\sum\limits_{k\gt n}v_k$  fail to converge to $0$ while $v_n\ll u_n$ since $U_n\to\infty$ by hypothesis.

Comment: Well, that was quick ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the divergence, we can partition $u_n$ into infinitely many segments
$$u_{n_{k-1}}+u_{n_{k-1}+1}+\ldots+u_{n_k-1}\ge k,$$
where $(n_k)$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers with $n_0=1$ (just add terms until it gets sufficiently large).

Now
$$\frac{u_{n_{k-1}}}k+\frac{u_{n_{k-1}+1}}k+\ldots+\frac{u_{n_k-1}}k\ge 1,$$
so these reduced segments still form a divergent sequence and it's $o(u_n)$ as we wanted.